# oracle: ALTER table to categorise rows with computed column?

Tags: sql, oracle, calculated-columns

I have this table `Shoe`:

```
Shoe size
---------
32
32
36
38
34
40
32
```

And I would like it to display Small for sizes 32-34, medium for 36 and big for 38 and above.

How should I change it using SQL?

I've done

```
ALTER TABLE Shoe 
  ADD Size varchar(50)
```

but I'm not sure how to do a `if shoe size >= 32 and <= 34, size = small` kind of command.

Is the only way to do it is to add them manually?

Comment: You can add a calculated column, what DBMS are you using?

Comment: Tag your question with the database that you use.

Comment: There is a nice documentation page on calculated column for oracle: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E57185_01/ESBTR/rw_calculate_column.html

Comment: @Luuk that is a link to an Oracle app doc, it is not SQL. The appropriate term for the functionality in Oracle DB is a virtual column not a computed column.

Comment: Ok, for virtual column you will have to look at: https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/virtual-columns-11gr1

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to *view* this classification of your data, you could just create a query or view using a `CASE` expression:

```sql
SELECT
    size,
    CASE WHEN size >= 32 AND size < 34 THEN 'small'
         WHEN size >= 34 AND size < 40 THEN 'medium'
         ELSE 'large' END AS label
FROM Shoe;
```

Answer (score 1):

For Oracle:

Query to add computed column:

```
 ALTER TABLE shoe ADD  sizes varchar(10) AS (CASE WHEN shoesize in(32,33,34) THEN 'small'
           WHEN shoesize in(35,36,37) THEN 'medium'
           WHEN shoesize>=38 THEN 'big' END ) ;
```

Select statements:

```
 select * from shoe;
```

Output:

| SHOESIZE | SIZES |
| --- | --- |
| 32 | small |
| 32 | small |
| 36 | medium |
| 34 | small |
| 40 | big |
| 32 | small |
| 38 | big |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=7622835d154ae0f82c267271bd2f9ae1)*

If you are using sql server you can add an computed column as below:

Schema and insert statements:

```
 create table shoe(shoesize int)
 
 INSERT INTO shoe(shoesize) VALUES(32),(32),(36),(38),(34),(40),(32);
```

Query to add computed column:

```
  ALTER TABLE shoe ADD size AS (CASE WHEN shoesize in(32,33,34) THEN 'small'
          WHEN shoesize in(35,36,37) THEN 'medium'
          when shoesize>=38 THEN'big' END );
```

Select from Shoe:

```
 select * from shoe
```

Output:

| shoesize | size |
| --- | --- |
| 32 | small |
| 32 | small |
| 36 | medium |
| 38 | big |
| 34 | small |
| 40 | big |
| 32 | small |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e125a5715fb2937bbe2a13aa5a1f4701)*

If you are using MySql then:

Schema and insert statements:

```
 create table shoe(shoesize int);
 
 INSERT INTO shoe VALUES (32);
 INSERT INTO shoe VALUES (32);
 INSERT INTO shoe VALUES (36);
 INSERT INTO shoe VALUES (38);
 INSERT INTO shoe VALUES (34);
 INSERT INTO shoe VALUES (40);
 INSERT INTO shoe VALUES (32);
```

Query to add computed column:

```
 ALTER TABLE shoe ADD COLUMN size VARCHAR(10) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (CASE WHEN shoesize in(32,33,34) THEN 'small'
          WHEN shoesize in(35,36,37) THEN 'medium'
          when shoesize>=38 THEN'big' END );
```

Select from shoe:

```
 select * from shoe
```

Output:

| shoesize | size |
| --- | --- |
| 32 | small |
| 32 | small |
| 36 | medium |
| 38 | big |
| 34 | small |
| 40 | big |
| 32 | small |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ae663e500d26f16a1a52ac402242b04d)*

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned `ALTER`, that's a DDL which modifies table's *description*. In that case, you'd use a virtual column.

For sample data you posted:

```
SQL> select * from shoe;

 SHOE_SIZE
----------
        32
        36
        38
        34
        40
        32

6 rows selected.
```

you'd then

```
SQL> alter table shoe add
  2    description varchar2(10) generated always as
  3      (case when shoe_size <= 34 then 'small'
  4            when shoe_size  > 34 and shoe_size <= 40 then 'medium'
  5            else 'large'
  6       end)
  7    virtual;

Table altered.
```

The result is:

```
SQL> select * from shoe;

 SHOE_SIZE DESCRIPTION
---------- -----------
        32 small
        36 medium
        38 medium
        34 small
        40 medium
        32 small

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

---

However, that's probably not the *best* option you have. Why? Because you might change your mind and decide to modify descriptions. A simpler/better option would  be to create a view:

```
SQL> create or replace view v_shoe as
  2    select shoe_size,
  3      case when shoe_size <= 34 then 'small'
  4           when shoe_size  > 34 and shoe_size <= 40 then 'medium'
  5           else 'large'
  6      end as description
  7  from shoe;

View created.

SQL> select * from v_shoe;

 SHOE_SIZE DESCRIPTIO
---------- ----------
        32 small
        36 medium
        38 medium
        34 small
        40 medium
        32 small

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

---

Or, yet another option: a *detail* table (can't reference the `shoe` table via referential integrity constraint as `shoe_size` can't be primary nor unique key because it allows duplicates):

```
SQL> select * from shoe_description;

 SHOE_SIZE DESCRIPTION
---------- -----------
        28 extra small
        30 small
        32 small
        34 small
        36 medium
        38 medium
        40 medium
        42 large
        44 large
        46 large

10 rows selected.

SQL>
SQL> select s.shoe_size, d.description
  2  from shoe s join shoe_Description d on d.shoe_size = s.shoe_size;

 SHOE_SIZE DESCRIPTION
---------- -----------
        32 small
        32 small
        34 small
        36 medium
        38 medium
        40 medium

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

---

Or, using a function which does the job; though, there's something potentially *wrong* with such an option - context switching (from SQL to PL/SQL) so performance might suffer if there are a LOT (really a lot) of shoes you're dealing with:

```
SQL> create or replace function f_shoe_desc(par_shoe_size in number)
  2    return varchar2
  3  is
  4    retval varchar2(20);
  5  begin
  6    retval := case when par_shoe_size <= 34 then 'small'
  7                   when par_shoe_size  > 34 and par_shoe_size <= 40 then 'medium'
  8                   else 'large'
  9              end;
 10    return retval;
 11  end;
 12  /

Function created.

SQL> select shoe_size, f_shoe_desc(shoe_size) description
  2  from shoe;

 SHOE_SIZE DESCRIPTION
---------- -----------
        32 small
        36 medium
        38 medium
        34 small
        40 medium
        32 small

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

---

I think I prefer the **view** option.